# C# best approach approach to read excel data

Tags: c#, import

I create a plugin for a game and some of the data I use to create my plugin DB is generated in excel.
What I am doing so far is generating the table in excel and use Copy-Paste to my C#.
e.g. I copy this:
[image]

And paste it in my code here:

```
 CommHelper.Creator(vaProxy, "AWACSDeclare", "Q", 1, "2", "declare", commExpHash);
 CommHelper.Creator(vaProxy, "AWACSRequestHelp", "Q", 1, "3", "request help", commExpHash);
 CommHelper.Creator(vaProxy, "AWACSWilco", "Q", 1, "4", "wilco", commExpHash);
 CommHelper.Creator(vaProxy, "AWACSUnable", "Q", 1, "5", "unable", commExpHash);
```

At the beginning I only had a few commands, but now I have many more.
What is the bets approach to achieve this?
I was thinking of saving the entire excel tab and add the actual missing (headers and footer) but this may cause sync issues in VS as I am creating the file externally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create an Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file in C# without installing Microsoft Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/how-do-i-create-an-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-in-c-sharp-without-installing-mic)

Comment: No,
I do not want to create an excel sheet. I want to import data from it.